# Algebraic description of Parallel vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $a,b,c\in \Bbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$.

If I use the geometric meaning of cross product and inner product. i.e $a\times b=|a||b|\sin\theta\hat n$, $\langle a,b\rangle=|a||b|\cos\theta$, it is clear that $a,b$ is parallel if $\langle a,b\rangle =|a||b|$ or $a\times b=0$.

But if I take $a=\lambda b$ for some real $\lambda$ as the definition of $a,b$ being parallel, I am stuck at showing the equivalence between $\langle a,b\rangle =|a||b|$ and $a\times b=0$ and $a,b$ being parallel. i.e $\langle a,b\rangle =|a||b|$ iff $a\times b=0$ iff $a,b$ are parallel.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The cross product of linearly dependent vectors is $\vec{0}$.

Comment: yes, what about the converse? @CSquared

Comment: I want to say that if $a\times b=0$ and both $a$ and $b$ are not zero, and $\lambda$ is not zero, then $a$ and $b$ are either parallel or anti-parallel.

Comment: Check out the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @Stahl thank you. Do you have any hint for equivalence between the cross product being 0 and the vectors being parallel?

Comment: @CSquared yes, i know this. I am asking if i can prove the algebraic equivalence. i.e $a\times b=0$ iff $a,b$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: If $a = \lambda b,$ then $a\times b = \lambda (b\times b).$ But $v\times w = -w\times v,$ so $b\times b = -b\times b\implies b\times b = \vec{0},$ so $\lambda(b\times b) = \vec{0}$ as well. On the other hand, if $a\times b = \vec{0},$ you can consider what this implies about the components and do some nasty casework based on components being zero/non-zero to show the result. There might be a quicker way, but I would need to think more on it.

Comment: @JMP edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $a,b$ are non-zero vectors and $\langle a,b\rangle=|a||b|$. This means that the angle between the vectors is $0$ and that $a$ and $b$, which implies that they are linearly dependent, thus their cross product is zero.

Now suppose that $a,b$ are non-zero vectors with non-zero components, $m,n\neq 0$ are a real scalars, and  the cross product of $a$ and $b$ is $0$. Since we are in $\mathbb{R^3}$, let us define $a$ as $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $b$ as $\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now, $$a\times b= (a_2b_3-a_3b_2)i-(a_1b_3-a_3b_1)j+(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)k=\vec{0}$$ so we must have that $a_2b_3=a_3b_2$ , $a_1b_3=a_3b_1$, and $a_1b_2=a_2b_1$, which also implies that $\frac{a_2}{a_3}=\frac{b_2}{b_3}$, $\frac{a_1}{a_3}=\frac{b_1}{b_3}$, and $\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{b_1}{b_2}$. The only way that this is possible is if $b$ is linearly dependent on $a$ and vice versa.

Remark (probably not a profound one): This is extremely similar to similar triangles and proportional side lengths.

So suppose $b_1=ma_1$ and $b_3=ma_3$. Now suppose $b_2=na_2$. But $\frac{a_2}{a_3}=\frac{b_2}{b_3}=\frac{na_2}{ma_3}$ implies that $n=m$ so then $a=mb$. Now we have that $a$ is linearly dependent on $b$ so that the angle between the vectors is $0$ and thus the dot product is $|a||b|$.

WLOG, consider the case when $a_1=0$. Then we must have that some of $a_2,a_3,$ or $b_1$ be zero. Note that $a_2$ and $a_3$ can't both be zero, or else $a$ would be the zero vector.

Case 1: Let $a_2=0$. Then either $a_3$ or $b_2$ is zero. So $b_2$ is zero. Now for the cross product to be zero, we must have that $b_1$ be zero, so then vectors $a$ and $b$ each have their third components as free variables, which implies that they are linearly dependent. Since $a_2=0$ implies that $b_1=0$, having them both be zero at the same time would not yield anything new.

Case 2: Let $a_3=0$. Now, $a_2\neq 0$ so we must have that $b_3=0$. Then $b_1=0$. So now vectors $a$ and $b$ each have their second components as free variables and are linearly dependent.

Case 3: Let $b_1=0$. Then for $a\times b=0$, we must have that at least one of $a_2, b_3$ be zero and one of $a_3,b_2$ be zero. If we choose $b_3=0$, then $a_3=0$. If we choose $b_2=0$, then $a_2=0$. If we choose $a_2=0$, then $b_2=0$. Finally, if we choose $a_3=0$, then $b_3=0$. In each case, we get that $a$ and $b$ are linearly dependent.

So if even one component of $a$ or $b$ is zero, for the cross product to be zero, they must be linearly dependent.

Since you suggested using geometric definitions, $a\times b=0=|a||b|\sin{\theta}\Longrightarrow \theta =0$ for non-zero vectors.

The other implications are quite easy to prove IMO.

Comment: thank you for your kindness. it is clear enough.

Comment: @briantylf sorry if its verbose or superfluous; its just how I think through problems

Comment: it is okay, I can catch the flow.

Answer (score 0):

With $\vec a=\lambda \vec b$, the cross product tells us that:

$$\vec a\times \vec b= (\lambda b_2b_3-\lambda b_3b_2)\vec i-(\lambda b_1b_3-\lambda b_3b_1)\vec j+(\lambda b_1b_2-\lambda b_2b_1)\vec k=0$$

The dot product becomes:

$$\pmatrix{\lambda b_1\\\lambda b_2\\\lambda b_3}\cdot\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2\\b_3} = \lambda (b_1^2+ b_2^2+ b_3^2)$$

And $$|a|=|\lambda b|=\sqrt{\lambda^2 (b_1^2+ b_2^2+ b_3^2)}=\lambda\sqrt{(b_1^2+ b_2^2+ b_3^2)}$$
$$|b|=\sqrt{b_1^2+ b_2^2+ b_3^2}$$
so  $$|a||b|=\lambda (b_1^2+ b_2^2+ b_3^2)$$